# Ruby: implement a new way of commenting

Tags: ruby

I like to comment out parts of my code while testing but in Ruby it's not so easy as compared to other languages. I'm aware of the current Ruby ways to comment but wonder if an alternative is possible. The code here is obviously not working, and i guess many have reasons not to do so, but could it be done ?

```
def /*
  =begin
end
def */
  =end
end

/*testing*/
//testing

/*
testing
on multiple lines
*/

puts 'test'
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to hack ruby parser, or do you want to comment some code? What's your quertion?

Comment: i wonder if it is possible to make possible commenting like that in Ruby, hacking the Ruby decoder is above my expectations

Comment: No, you obviously can't do this. Why would you expect this to work? Those are are C-style comments. Ruby doesn't use them.

Comment: i' m aware that it isn't working meagar, but COULD id be made working i wonder ?

Comment: Of course you *could* make it work, but that would mean that you'd have to fork Ruby and modify the parser to make it work. But there's no good or compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @peter No, the answer is that it can't be done. It is not a case of technical limitations, **the language doesn't support this**. Regardless of how you make this work, as soon as you do you are **no longer writing Ruby**. You'll have produced a broken dialect of Ruby that only your interpreter understands.

Comment: Without forking Ruby or otherwise twiddling with its parser, you can always invoke the C pre-processor or the m4 pre-processor as part of a build process to transform your code in practically any way you want. Of course, this makes your code non-portable without also bringing your build environment along with it.

Comment: So the short answer is No, can one of you also put this in an answer ? The other answers only give existing ways to comment, what was not my question.

Comment: Why not just use an editor that supports multi line commenting like SublimeText or Textmate or Gedit with plugins or vim?

Comment: @bruno077 that is circumventing the problem, i sometimes do, still i feel it's a flaw in Ruby

Comment: @peter like most people have mentioned, you are welcome to fork and create your own version of ruby with comments as you like =). I don't mind the current method of commenting, I don't think it's a flaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can comment out multiple lines by using `=begin` and `=end`, but they must be located at the beginning of the line.

```
class TestClass

  def my_method

  end

=begin
  def another_method
    # ...
  end
=end

end
```

Beyond this, the answer is that it can't be done. You cannot use C-style multiline comments in Ruby. It is not a case of technical limitations, the language doesn't support this. Regardless of how you make this work, as soon as you do you are no longer writing Ruby. You'll have produced a broken dialect of Ruby that only your interpreter understands.

Comment: I (personally) never use this syntax. textmate makes it much easier :)

Comment: thanks, but i'm aware of the existing possibilities, edited my question to make that clear, that they have to be at the beginning of the line is one of the reasons i often wish there was an alternative other than put a # on every line or this technique (or others that are not better)

Comment: @Sergio That's wonderful for you and Textmate. I don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Modern editors/IDEs should facilitate mass code commenting. I used [IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), they both allow it. You select a piece of code, hit Cmd+/ and all lines get commented out with single-line comments. Hit Cmd+/ again and code is uncommented. Very handy.

Comment: thanks, but i'm aware of the existing possibilities, edited my question to make that clear

Comment: Well, then you have no choice but to hack on ruby parser if you want C-style comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby comments start with # character outside of a string literal.

You can comment out multiple lines at a time by using your editor's "column" mode to insert # as the first character on a line.

Example:

```
def foo
#  ...
#end
#def bar
#  ...
end
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm aware of the existing possibilities, edited my question to make that clear